# Simplifying expression that has cubic power of del operator

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, laplacian, divergence-operator

How can I apply the $\nabla^3$ operator in the following expression?
$$
\nabla^3\cdot \left( \mathbf{F(r)}g(\mathbf{r}) \right)
$$
here $\mathbf{F(r)}$ is a vector and $g(\mathbf{r})$ is a scalar. Is there any identity to simplify the above expression?

I am looking for a way to write this expression where $\nabla$ operator directly applies to $g(\mathbf{r})$.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Summary_of_important_identities) help?

Comment: $\def\n{\nabla}$I assume that $\,\n^3\cdot F\,$ is a non-standard way of writing $\,\n^2\left(\n\cdot F\right)$

Comment: @student91 Yes. It helped. Thank you

Comment: @greg yes exactly.